# Adicionar header em http request ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

estou com problema para enviar headers, quando eu coloco os headers não funciona no APK, somente no navegador, mas se eu tirar as linhas e não enviar nenhum header ele funciona normalmente.

No navegador funciona os 2 exemplos, no celular só funciona a segunda imagem, não sei se é CORS pq eu não consigo dar uma alert na requisição...

O código: https://pastebin.com/nQY7Gz8e

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

É normal desenvolvedores cairem nesse problema, isso acontece porque seu aplicativo tenta acessar algo externo uma *"a url da api"* e para proteger você de um acesso externo ele bloqueia essa requisição.

mas porque no navegador funciona? Aposto que a api e o navegador estão rodando no mesmo PC então a requisição não é bloqueada.

Para entender mais sobre o CORS : [Controle de Acesso HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS)

Algumas soluções possiveis pode ser:

- Enviar Parametros pelo **Headers** durante a requisição =>  **{ Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * }**
- Adicionar um proxy para consumir a api.
- Usar a Lib [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) na api

Espero ter ajudado :)